# JavaScript Cheat Sheet

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a reference card for JavaScript - for example a summary of syntax and methods parameters.  Google gives me lots of choices.  What is a good one?

Comment: if looking for ES6 https://ohmycheatsheet.com/es6/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, the one I use is the first hit on a Google search - [Added Bytes Cheat Sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/javascript-cheat-sheet/) .

Comment: Me too.  Those are the old ILoveJackDaniels ones.

Answer (score 2):

Danny Goodman's [JavaScript and Browser Objects Quick Reference](http://www.dannyg.com/dl/JSB6RefBooklet.pdf) is quite useful.

Comment: came here to recommend that. +1

Answer (score 1):

[Devguru](http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/ecmascript/quickref/javascript_intro.html) is a very good one that I use when in doubt.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spending a bit of money The VisiBone products are well worth the outlay!

[VisiBone Javascript](http://www.visibone.com/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

For basic stuff I recommend [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/JS/default.asp).  It's not great but it's an ok beginning.  For advanced stuff I recommend the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript).  For on the fly prototyping I recommend a [JavaScript Shell](http://www.squarefree.com/shell/) which can allow you to test what methods are available by doing something like `props(object)` which shows what properties (fields, methods) an object has.

Comment: @JanJongboom: Seriously? Are they so bad?

Comment: @JanJongboom That page didn't convince me that W3Schools is so bad that it should be strictly avoided. So there are a few mistakes or misleading statements here and there. It's not systematically bad or deceptive.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I like the [O'Reilly pocket reference books](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596004117) for stuff like this, they are inexpensive and come in handy here and there.

But, if you are looking for something online, I usually find a lot of good basic javascript (and HTML/CSS/etc..) stuff on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You may find a lot of JavaScript cheat sheets at [TechPosters](http://techposters.net/blog/javascript/) website.

Comment: The domain does not exist anymore.

Comment: It had interesting but short life :)

Answer (score -1):

This is new, but very good: [Encycode JavaScript Cheat Sheet](http://encycode.com/wiki/index.php/JavaScript_Cheat_Sheet)

Comment: Encycode.com does not seem to exist anymore, and I have just found loads of broken links there.